# Copying different files from different folders

Tags: command-line, copy

I have 400 folders (/123_0/, /123_1/, ...) and inside each one I have a file with extension *.root and different names.
I just want to copy these files to a destination /destination/.
How can I do it?

Comment: If this is a [school] homework assignment, you should do it yourself, or at least try (*going to sites like these where something doesn't do what you expected; providing us with your attempt seeking help on what you did wrong*).  I'd suggest `cp` to copy files, if you only want to copy the specified files, you could use `find` to locate them .. but it can be accomplished in many ways

Answer (score 0):

If all those 400 folders are in the same location, here is how you can do it:

```
cp **/*.root destination/
```